# Background disappears when button is pressed

Tags: java, swing

I have set up a game in Java using Swing UI.

#### Expected

When firing a projectile across the screen and I want the background to be constantly there

#### Issue

When I run the code the background appears to be fine.
But when the button to fire the projectile is pressed then the background disappears.

#### Code

```
public class ProjectileShooterTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame() {
        };

        ImageIcon background=new ImageIcon("Background.png");
        Image img=background.getImage();
        Image temp=img.getScaledInstance(800,440,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        background=new ImageIcon(temp);

        JLabel back=new JLabel(background);
        back.setBounds(0,0,800,500);

        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(800,500);

        final ProjectileShooter projectileShooter = new ProjectileShooter();
        ProjectileShooterPanel projectileShooterPanel = new ProjectileShooterPanel(projectileShooter);
        projectileShooter.setPaintingComponent(projectileShooterPanel);

        JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0));
        controlPanel.add(new JLabel("     Post-Launch Angle"));

        final JSlider angleSlider = new JSlider(70, 89, 85);
        angleSlider.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );

        controlPanel.add(angleSlider);
        f.add(back);

        controlPanel.add(new JLabel("                         Thrust"));
        final JSlider powerSlider = new JSlider(50, 80, 60);
        powerSlider.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
        controlPanel.add(powerSlider);


        JButton shootButton = new JButton("Launch");
        shootButton.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
        shootButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int angleDeg = angleSlider.getValue();
                int power = powerSlider.getValue();
                projectileShooter.setAngle(Math.toRadians(angleDeg));
                projectileShooter.setPower(power);
                projectileShooter.shoot();
            }
        });
        f.add(back);
        controlPanel.add(shootButton);

        f.getContentPane().add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.getContentPane().add(projectileShooterPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    }
}

class ProjectileShooter
{
    private double angleRad = Math.toRadians(45);
    private double power = 50;
    private Projectile projectile;
    private JComponent paintingComponent;

    void setPaintingComponent(JComponent paintingComponent)
    {
        this.paintingComponent = paintingComponent;
    }

    void setAngle(double angleRad)
    {
        this.angleRad = angleRad;
    }

    void setPower(double power)
    {
        this.power = power;
    }

    void shoot()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                executeShot();
            }
        });
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
    }

    private void executeShot()
    {
        if (projectile != null)
        {
            return;
        }
        projectile = new Projectile();

        Point2D velocity =
                AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(angleRad).
                        transform(new Point2D.Double(1,0), null);
        velocity.setLocation(
                velocity.getX() * power * 0.5,
                velocity.getY() * power * 0.5);
        projectile.setVelocity(velocity);
        //System.out.println("Initial "+velocity);


        long prevTime = System.nanoTime();
        while (projectile.getPosition().getY() >= 0)
        {
            long currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            double dt = 3 * (currentTime - prevTime) / 1e8;
            projectile.performTimeStep(dt);

            prevTime = currentTime;
            paintingComponent.repaint();
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                return;
            }
        }

        projectile = null;
        paintingComponent.repaint();
    }

    Projectile getProjectile()
    {
        return projectile;
    }

}
```

#### Question

How can I solve this?

Comment: Where is the code and class definition of object `projectileShooter` and also of class  `ProjectileShooterPanel` ? Please give a [example].

Comment: My background is now covering my projectile, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
f.add(back);
```

is equivalent to:

```
f.getContentPane().add(back, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Later in your code you do:

```
f.getContentPane().add(projectileShooterPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Which will cause problems because you can't add two components to the CENTER.

A Swing GUI is parent/child design so you need something like:

```
f.getContentPane().add(back, BorderLayout.CENTER);
back.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
back.add(projectileShooterPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I'll let you figure out the logic order and placement of the above statements.

Also why do you have:

```
f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

at the end of the constructor? This replaces all the constraint information of your original layout.

Finally, your projectile shooter panel needs to be transparent, otherwise it will paint over top of the background. So you also need:

```
projectileShooterPanel.setOpaque( false );
```

Note: instead of using the JLabel as the background it would be easier to paint the background in your projectile shooter panel. Then you won't have issues with trying to add multiple panels to one another and the shooter panel won't need to be transparent.

Edit:

You need a parent/child relationship between your components like:

```
- frame
    - content pane
        - background image 
            - projectile panel
                - projectile
```

My first suggestion was to make the background a component and add the projectile panel to it:

1. set the layout of the background component
2. add the projectile panel to the background
3. make the projectile panel transparent so you can see the image

This is not the best solution

The second solution was to paint the background as part of the projectile panel:

1. paint the background image in the projectile panel
2. paint the projectile

This is the preferred solution.

Comment: How do you suggest I paint the background in the projectile shooter panel. Is my problem not that when I shoot the projectile the panel is updated and doesn't include the background?

Comment: You use the `Graphics.drawImage(....)` method in the `paintComponent(...)` method of the panel. For example check out [Background Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/)

Comment: Is my problem not that when the panel is updated after I shoot my projectile it isn't including my background?

Comment: I have managed to get my background to stay on the whole time but it now covers my projectile (I can see it flying at the top of the gui where the background doesn't reach) any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Two suggestion were given: 1) Add the projectile panel to the background. Why did you do it the other way? 2) do the painting of the image on the projectile panel instead of using a label.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, I'm really not very good at java so it took me some time, I have managed to get this working now by painting it in the projectile panel. However, there is now a huge frame rate loss. Any ideas on how that can be resolved?

Comment: This is now a different question and we can't guess how you changed the above code. Ask a new question with an updated [mre]. My guess is that you read the image in the paintComponent() method which is wrong. A painting method is for painting only so it can be as fast as possible.